# Facebook API: Get a response if user clicked on send

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

When I am sending a request, I need to found whether the user has clicked on `send` or `cancel`. For now I have this code:

```
FB.init({
    appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
    cookie: true,
    status: true, 
    xfbml: true, 
});

FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'click!',
    to: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function to capture the response.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'click!',
    to: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
},function (request, to) {
            if (request && to) {
                // User completed the request to at least 1 user
            }else{
                // User did not complete the request
            }
        });
```

Comment: When I use this, so I get always option for else even I choose Sen request and my request was post.

Comment: Didn't realize you were using `apprequests`, edited the callback accordingly.

Comment: And, how can I this resolve? What method I must choose? 
Otherwise, I thank you for your advice. 
@cdbconcepts